# boost log file rotation and compression

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I am trying to have a log rotation and compression with boost log.

Compression is simple to setup with a gzipped stream and a text stream. But text stream does not handle rotation.
[How to use a compressor Boost::Iostreams filter as a sink in Boost::Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110882/how-to-use-a-compressor-boostiostreams-filter-as-a-sink-in-boostlog)

Rotation with text_file is out over the box but does not take a stream as input.
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sink_backends.html#log.detailed.sink_backends.text_file

How to have compression and rotation?